# jQuery - Validate date on datetime picker click on SharePoint

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint

I have developed a custom Web Part on SharePoint 2013.

I'm using the default date picker control. I also have an array with all the holidays in Italy, and I would like to "validate" the selected date just after the user clicks on the datetimepicker. Validate in my case should be print an alert message if the selected date is a holiday.

I've tried this code, but it is not firing:

```
$(".ms-picker-table a").on("click",function() {
    console.log("ON CLICK DATEPICKER");
    /* DATES CHECK */
    [...]
});
```

`ms-picker-table` is the class of the date picker control.

`a` elements inside this table already contain code in `href` attribute:

```
javascript:ClickDay('01\u002f06\u002f2017')
```

I don't know if it can create problems.

Also parent td element of each link has this code:

```
onclick="javascript:ClickDay('01\u002f06\u002f2017')"
```

So is there a way to correct my code to check dates when a user select a value from datepicker?

Answer (score 0):

onBlur event should do the job

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="date" id="dateField">

<script>
$("input[id*='dateField']").blur(function(){
    var dateValue=$("input[id='dateField']").val();
    console.log(dateValue);
   // check array to see if the date is in the Array
});
</script>
```